# Render a component in a specific section of page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

MainComponent.jsx

```
//other code
<CardGroup>
  <Router>
    {cards.map((value,idx) => { return <TutorialCard key={idx} val={value} /> })}
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/subject/:title" children={(props)=>{<ContentPage {...props}/>}}/>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
</CardGroup>
//other code
```

ContentPage.jsx

I want to show this component in a specific section/new page.

```
export default function CotentPage(props){
  return <h1>This is content page-{props.match.params.title}</h1>  
}
```

TutorialCard.jsx

```
//this component create links.
export default function tutorialCard({ val }) {
  return (
    <Card border="primary" style={{ width: '18rem' }} className='cards'>
      <Link exact to={`/subject/${val}`}>
        <Card.Header className="text-center">
          <h6>{val}</h6>   
        </Card.Header>
        <Card.Body>
          <img src={cardSvg} className="fitImage"></img>
        </Card.Body>
      </Link>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

[image: These are links genarated by TutorialCard.jsx component]
After clicking these links it render ContentPage besides links. But I want to render ContentPage in a new page. how can I achieve this?
Please Help!

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-react-router-include-router-hooks/

Comment: and what is the problem here?

Comment: ContentPage component is showing besides link. I want to show it in a specific section/new page.

Comment: your question is unclear. could you add some more infomation?

Comment: @NITHINPB I have add more information. Please check it.

Comment: @RashedulIslamEmon you are always rendering  `TutorialCard` irrespective of your current route. it will always appear in your page, to get rid of that problem. configure a separate route for `TutorialCard`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, the cards are rendered independent from your routes. You need to render your cards in another route. Like so:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route
      path="/"
      exact
      children={() => (cards.map((value, idx) => <TutorialCard key={idx} val={value} />))}
    />
    <Route
      path="/subject/:title"
      children={(props) => <ContentPage {...props} />}
    />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: it's not working. Links are not rendering while using these code.

Comment: Are you sure you're in the `/` path?